# Spring batch partitioner synchronization between 2 jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am having two spring batch jobs.
1)Fetch data from DB and create CSV file of the fetched data.(Runs in every 15 mins) 
2)Index the created CSV file to solr.(Runs in every 10 mins)

These 2 jobs are running in parallel as cron.I want to add partitioner to the csv to solr job for fast processing.

The problem is that some time the csv to solr job picks up the csv which is still in process of getting data from DB to CSV job.So want to pick up only that CSVs which is fully loaded with data and provide that file to partitioner.
Please tell me way forward to it.

Comment: Do you keep those intermediate CSV files after indexing them in Solr? If not, have you thought about reading from the DB and indexing in Solr directly? That would be more efficient and would fix your issue by design.

Comment: yes i keep those intermediate files after indexing .

Comment: ok. I think it is easier to make a single job with two sequential steps. This will make sure step 2 does not start before step 1 has finished writing the entire csv and you would not need to synchronize both schedules.